# how to create a table structure from column values of another table in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a scenario where i have the entries in a column of a table with CSV ( these are dynamic values). I need to generate the tables with those values in sqlserver(MSSQL)

Input Table

```
Value   
FirstName,LastName,SSN  
Address1,City,Zip
HomePhone,CellPhone
```

Output Table1

```
FirstName   LastName    SSN
```

Output Table2

```
Address1    City    Zip
```

Output Table3

```
HomePhone   CellPhone
```

Can some one please help me.

Comment: Why? And how do you want to maintain a relationship between these tables?

Comment: Hi Aaron,The column values are dynamically generated so i cannot hardcore them there is a master table which has the firstvalue as a Foriegn Key, example in first row FirstName is a foreign key in the master table and address1 in row 2 is a Foreign key in master and so on.

Comment: Does this "master table" also contain data types? What is the purpose of this design?

Comment: Master table is metadata table we are planing to build a small data warehouse model

Comment: This doesn't sound anything at all like a data warehouse (which likes "dynamically generated columns" even less than a normal application database).  On the other hand, it does sound a whole lot like an E.A.V. (Entity-Attribute-Value) data model.  If so, you should recognize it ahead of time and do your research, because it is a whole lot of extra work.  The Wikipedia article has a fair explanation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model.

Comment: Thanks Barry, Yes it is something like a EAV model. I would have an input   metadata table which have columns values of the corresponding tables that are supposed to be generated. I was searching for the solution online for the past 2 days in order to generate the output tables. once they are generated we are planing to create a ER model among the tables.

Comment: Well then, read the Wikipedia article closely.  Having looked at it again, I can say that it is just about the best general explanation and introduction to what this is, what you need, what some of your basic choices are and what you are in for.  Compared to a traditional relational model, this is going to seem like trying to build castles out of jelly.

Answer (score 1):

You need dynamic SQL for this, such as:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

with t as (
    select 'FirstName,LastName,SSN' as value union all
    select 'Address1,City,Zip' union all
    select 'HomePhone,CellPhone'
   )
select @sql = (select 'create table'+CAST(seqnum as varchar(255))+' ('+REPLACE(value, ',', ' varchar(255),') + ' varchar(255)); '
               from (select t.*, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
                     from t
                    ) t
               for xml path ('')
              )

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, I tried your query it is throwing error "Unknown object type 'table3' used in a CREATE, DROP, or ALTER statement." oops, now I added the keyword table in the create table syntax of the script and it worked.

Comment: but the above query generated only one table and it has the last row i.e a table got generated with Homephone and Cell phone only

Comment: @user2262518 . . . Sorry about that.  I would usually take the output of the query (which would be multiple lines) and throw them in an SSMS window.  You want a single statement, so that requires concatenating them together into one row.

Comment: Hi Gordon, yes, I need each table for each row of the input table. so in the above example there should be 3 tables for 3 rows

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

1. `Select FirstName,LastName,SSN into Table1 from #InputTable`
2. `Select Address1,City,Zip into Table2 from #InputTable`
3. `Select HomePhone,CellPhone into Table1 from #InputTable`

Comment: Hi Vijay, the columns are dynamic so i cannot hardcode them as columns